# jQuery - textarea value get converted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a texture where the user can write a small description. What I am trying to achieve is that while the user is typing another element text `h2` gets update.

everything works except that when the user uses specials characters such as `è é æ` emoticons etc they get converted in the `h2` element.

For example if I type `è` it gets converted to `e`.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c16aLs5j/)

```
 $('.dashTextArea').keyup(function() {
   var stt = $(this).val();
   $(".myDesc").text(stt);

 });
```

Comment: It looks good for me on jsfiddle, what browser are you using?

Comment: The fiddle works fine for me as well ?

Comment: and for chrome I get same results

Comment: Ok! found that as soon as you type they don't get converted, after I write the second letter it works

Answer (score 0):

For me, these "special" characters work and are well displayed. I think it's probably the encoding settings of your browser/webpage.